# Getting java.lang.IllegalStateException: Binder has been finalized! when calling disconnect() or close() android.bluetooth.BluetoothGatt

Tags: android, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy

I have Android application using [BluetoothGatt.java](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/master/core/java/android/bluetooth/BluetoothGatt.java).

The code block that is sometimes crashing (could not reproduce it but happens to users):

```
mBluetoothGatt.disconnect();
mBluetoothGatt.close();
mBluetoothGatt = null;
```

Stack trace for disconnect:

```
Fatal Exception: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Binder has been finalized!
   at android.os.BinderProxy.transactNative(Binder.java)
   at android.os.BinderProxy.transact(Binder.java:503)
   at android.bluetooth.IBluetoothGatt$Stub$Proxy.clientDisconnect(IBluetoothGatt.java:925)
   at android.bluetooth.BluetoothGatt.disconnect(BluetoothGatt.java:754)
```

Stack trace when it pass the disconnect but crashing at close()

```
Fatal Exception: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Binder has been finalized!
   at android.os.BinderProxy.transactNative(BinderProxy.java)
   at android.os.BinderProxy.transact(BinderProxy.java:503)
   at android.bluetooth.IBluetoothGatt$Stub$Proxy.unregisterClient(IBluetoothGatt.java:891)
   at android.bluetooth.BluetoothGatt.unregisterApp(BluetoothGatt.java:692)
   at android.bluetooth.BluetoothGatt.close(BluetoothGatt.java:631)
```

Crashes appear on wide range devices and android versions.
Code is executed always on main thread of the application

I would be grateful for any tips on what could be a cause.